# Laptop with Ubuntu Mate 15.04 screen dimming after 10 seconds

Tags: power-management, brightness, battery, 15.04, mate

I watch movies on Youtube, Popcorn or XBMC and after 10 seconds when I have my laptop disconnected from power the screen dims. I know that there is an option in `dconf-editor` for longer timeout but does not suit me. There is the option in `power-manager` to disable the screen dimming on battery/ac but I wouldn't like that option.

I would like something like caffeine but it does not work in Ubuntu MATE 15.04.

What should I do? It's annoying to disable screen dimming manually every time I watch a movie or video.

Comment: Why doesn't `dconf` suit you?

Comment: it does, but i would dimming to be stopped when i play a movie.